# list(dictionary) vs dictionary.keys() vs list(dictionary.keys()) in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a dictionary my_dict, we apply `list(my_dict)` and `my_dict.keys()` in the following code

```
my_dict = {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4}
list_keys = list(my_dict)
view_keys = my_dict.keys()
list_from_view = list(my_dict.keys())
print("list_keys : ", list_keys)
print("view_keys : ", view_keys)
print("list_from_view", list_from_view)
```

Results:

```
list_keys :  ['1', '2', '3', '4']
view_keys :  dict_keys(['1', '2', '3', '4'])
list_from_view ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

What are the differences between using list(my_dict), my_dict.keys(), and list(my_dict.keys()), especially:

1. **list(my_dict) vs my_dict.keys()**
2. **list(my_dict) vs list(my_dict.keys())**  (what is the best (fast) way to get a list of keys)

Thanks.

Comment: One more to your question: `[k for k in my_dict]`. my_dict.keys() returns a DictKeys and not a list.

Comment: "what is the best (fast) way to get a list of keys" - you can measure this

Comment: There would be negligible difference in all of them. I generally use dict.keys()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Python list is an iterable, but not all iterables are list...

Let us examine your expressions:

1. `list_keys = list(my_dict)`: here you use `my_dict` as an iterable over the keys and build a new list from it. Long story made short, you have copied the keys into a list. From that point on, you can apply any changes to the list or the initial dict without changing anything to the other object
2. `view_keys = my_dict.keys()`: here you get a `dict_keys` view on the dictionary. It is a non modifiable iterable that can be used to access the keys of the dictionary. If you add an item to the dictionary, you will see it immediately in the view, but you can neither add a new element to `view_keys` nor change or remove one
3. `list_from_view = list(my_dict.keys())`: here you access the view on the keys, and iterate it to build a list. In the end, it is exactly the same as the first way: you get an independent list

Which one is best? It depends.

As I have already said, 1 and 3 give equivalent lists. 1 is probably more *Pythonic* because it uses the fact that a Python dictionary is implicitly an iterable over its keys. 3 is probably easier to understand for new Python users because it explicitly references an operation on keys.

2 is a completely different animal because instead of having an independent list object, you have a view on the initial dictionary that will follow its changes.

Now for the question:

> what is the best (fast) way to get a list of keys

2 will not return a list of keys because a list have `append` or `remove` methods that a view has not

1 and 3 should be seen as equivalent on a performance point of view, and I have already spoken of readability which is the most important quality of Python code

The question that you should have asked:

> what is the more pythonic way to iterate over the list of keys of a dictionary?

With no doubt `for key in my_dict`. No need to convert that to a list, and a view is seldom necessary

Answer (score 1):

The major difference in these is between two types, namely `list` and `dict_keys`.

`list` is taking all the values from given keys at time and storing them into a `list` object.

`dict_keys` object on the other hand provides you with a view on dictionary keys.

Difference between these is shown in the following:

```
d = {1: 2, 3: 4}
a = d.keys()
b = list(d)

a
# dict_keys([1, 3])

b
# [1, 3]

d[5] = 6

a
# dict_keys([1, 3, 5])

b
# [1, 3]
```

In conclusion, `dict_keys` object will show you the updates to your `dict` as soon as they are introduced, while `list` will stay the same.

Should you make changes to the `list` those changes will not be reflected onto `dict`, while on the other hand you cannot make changes to `dict_keys`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this response is for (1. list(my_dict) vs my_dict.keys() ), and what about 2. list(my_dict) vs list(my_dict.keys())  ?

Comment: @ibra You can use `timeit` to check but generally `list(my_dict)` seems to be faster.